# Evaluation of definite integral in terms of Bessel function

Tags: special-functions

Can I express the integral $\int_0^1[\cos (xt)/(1-t^2)]dt$ in terms of Bessel Polynomial? I tried by putting $t=\sin \theta$ and used the integral representation of Bessel's polynomial $J_n(x)=(1/\pi)\int_0^\pi \cos(n\theta-x\sin \theta)d\theta$. I expect the answer may be $J_0(x)(\pi/2)$. But I did not get it even now. Help is solicited.

Comment: Why the original integral should be convergent? The integrand function has a non-integrable singularity in $t=1$. I bet you have forgotten a square root.

Answer (score 1):

Due to issues relating to convergence, the only values of *x* for which the integral converges are

of the form $x=(2k+1)~\dfrac\pi2$ , and the result is $I_{2k+1}=\dfrac\pi4\sqrt{|2k+1|}\cdot J^{(1,0)}\bigg(-\dfrac12~,~|2k+1|\dfrac\pi2\bigg)$,

for all $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: If, however, you meant $\sqrt{1-t^2}$, as @Jack suggested, then the result is $I(x)=\dfrac\pi2~J_0(x)~$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: ... by just setting $t=\sin \theta$.

Comment: Yes. It is a an error on my part. It is $\sqrt{1-t^2}$. How can I change the limits from $(0,\pi/2)$ to $(0,\pi)$

Comment: **Hint:** $~\sin\bigg(\dfrac\pi2+u\bigg)~=~?$